# Как при помощи :hover убрать текст из блока, и можно ли это сделать?

Tags: css, hover

Вот такая ситуация:

https://jsfiddle.net/cg1pubv6/

```css
.recent_work__column__w2 {
  width: 262px;
  height: 320px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
.recent_work__column__w2:hover {
  width: 262px;
  height: 320px;
  background: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="recent_work__column__w2">
    <p class="recent_work__column__title">Brand</p>
    <p class="recent_work__column__tagline">tagline here</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Нужно при наведении на блок (когда он меняет цвет), чтобы исчезал сам текст. как этого добиться?

Comment: .recent_work__column__w2:hover p{ opacity: 0; }

Comment: спасибо, круто!

Comment: @Идентикон, если ответ вам подошел, примите его (нажмите серую галочку под рейтингом ответа)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1  - `recent_work__column__w2:hover p{opacity: 0;}`

Вариант 2  -  `.recent_work__column__w2:hover p{display: none;}`

Вариант 3  -  `.recent_work__column__w2:hover p{transform: scale(0);}`

```css
.recent_work__column__w2 {
  width: 262px;
  height: 320px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.recent_work__column__w2 {
  width: 262px;
  height: 320px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
.recent_work__column__w2:hover {
  width: 262px;
  height: 320px;
  background: green;
  display: block;
}

/*--- #1 --- */

.recent_work__column__w2:hover p {
  opacity: 0;
}


/*--- #2 --- */

/*.recent_work__column__w2:hover p{
  display: none;
}*/


/*--- #3 --- */

/*.recent_work__column__w2:hover p{
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}*/
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="recent_work__column__w2">
    <p class="recent_work__column__title">Brand</p>
    <p class="recent_work__column__tagline">tagline here</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.recent_work__column__w2 {
  width: 262px;
  height: 320px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
}

.recent_work__column__w2:hover {
  width: 262px;
  height: 320px;
  background: green;
  display: block;
}

.recent_work__column__w2:hover > * {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="recent_work__column__w2">
    <p class="recent_work__column__title">Brand</p>
    <p class="recent_work__column__tagline">tagline here</p>
  </a>
</div>
```